# In-Navigation Status Bar iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Google maps already has a blue bar that appears whenever you are in navigation.  I want to know how I can implement this myself.  Any ideas?

[image: Google Maps in navigation]

Comment: You don't, the system does it for you.

Comment: It's not a feature of Google Maps. It's a feature of iOS when ever an app is actively providing directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure your app to use Core Location *in the background*. And when, as you must now do in iOS 8, you come to request authorization, request When In Use authorization.

The blue bar will then appear automatically whenever your app is using core location in the background.

Comment: Isn't the blue bar for navigation apps, not just due to an app using core location?

Comment: @rmaddy My color sense isn't that strong, so maybe you get another color when using core location. But the bar definitely means using core location in background and it definitely comes with When In Use authorization.

Comment: My app does already use location in the background but I do not get this blue bar.

Comment: Read carefully what I said. It also depends on the When In Use authorization. Your app has Always authorization. That is why you don't see the blue bar.