# How to implement such indication effect on the status bar like Google Map in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I assume this is an interesting question. I'm wondering how to implement such UX effect on an IOS application. For example, when using google map on my phone after I exit the app, not closing it just exit to home or switch to other apps, it stays in my status bar which is a great UX design implementation.

How did they do this? Is there any documentation I missed in the developer library? I would like to read if someone can provide me any guidance here.

Thanks!

[image: Actually using the Google Map App]
[image: When I exit the Google Map App, it shows up in the status bar]

Comment: This is an OS feature that specifically indicates to the user that an app is using his/her location. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760740/in-navigation-status-bar-ios