# How change the status bar color in the iOS system with my app running on background

Tags: ios, statusbar

How can I set a status bar color and keep it on all apps and system like at the image below?

[image: [sample image]]

Comment: You can't - at least not without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow. One thing about iOS that makes it very different from other mobile platforms is that you only have a very finite sandbox to play in as a developer. There are a lot of global phone-wide settings and capabilities that you simply don't have access to. So while you can't change the status bar color at will, iOS will notify you if something is going on behind the scenes.

You'll notice that when navigating using Google Maps you'll see this:

[image]

Also there's this SO article on this very question: [Nav Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760740/in-navigation-status-bar-ios)

It's blue when an app is using your location in the background and red when you're recording from the microphone.

So it's a system-generated thing that you don't have direct control over.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The screen shot shows the red coloring which iOS adds whenever the microphone is open.  Notice the text at the right.

Comment: My answer to the question is "you can't change the status bar color at will" as stated above. I then provided a little background on what was happening in Norman's screenshot there. So I think the question here was "can I make a red header like I see here?" and the answer is "sorry, but developers have no control over that feature, you can only put the app in a certain state and allow iOS to give a banner at the top with a color coordinating to what background function is happening"

Comment: The screenshot shows an active microphone app. That's why it's red. If it was a nav app it would be blue, if it was a phone app it would be green.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for that. You get this color from system to indicate that one of the apps uses your microphone at background, just to inform the user. Same happens with blue color if app uses geolocation services. And you may notice that if you turn on internet sharing, this also will be the case

Answer (score -1):

To get the effect in the screen shot, just open the microphone for recording.  iOS will then do the coloring automatically.  You will need to set the UIBackgroundModes to include audio, and manage your audio session properly.

Comment: Your statement is true, but it will lead to serious troubles. Background audio session will consume battery, and if there is no need for that app to audio recording, especially in background, that will not pass AppStore review. Please do not recommend it, this is a bad practice overall

Comment: @azat, I did not mean to do this if you are not using audio.  Do you seriously believe anyone would want to turn the status bar red and have it say "recording voice" unless they are recording audio for a reason?